# Css rules unit test in react material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jestjs, enzyme

For a react component built using material-ui(next), material-ui styling solution can be used to create a style sheet and inject it.

```
const styleSheet = theme => {
  return{
   default: {
     color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText
   },
 }
```

How can we add unit tests for the same? What i am interested is in unit testing the css rules applied, not the classname. For eg in this case default class should have a color property and its value should be equal to `theme.palette.primary.contrastText`